# Problem with py to exe . tkinter widgets not visible

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe, data-entry

I have made a GUI using tkinter and then converted the py file to exe. But some widgets like the DateEntry widget is not visible in the exe file.
I have to submit for board practical.

Comment: You have to include `import babel.numbers` in your code and then make an exe OR use `--hidden-import babel.numbers` in your `pyinstaller` code.

Comment: Did you, per chance, forget to include a module when running pyinstaller? Also, what exactly do you mean by 'not visible'? Is it invisible but there, does the function that should call it raise an error or does it just not appear when it should?